# How to fetch two objects results from controller to view in Laravel5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here is my controller code for fetching two objects. At end of each object i am using ->get(); that shows error undefied variable. But when  i use ->first(); it works fine but show only first record. but i need the whole record.

```
public function ratingdata()
{
      $pacra['pacra'] = DB::table('og_ratings AS p')

           ->select('p.client_id as Id','p.ppl_date as Ppl','p.notification_date as Notification ',
            'p.dissemination_date as Dissemination', 'p.rating_type_id as ratingTypeId',
            'p.rating_scale_id',  'p.pacra_action as Action' , 'og_companies.name as Entity',
            'og_main_sectors.title as Industry', 'p.detail_report as DetailReport', 

            ) 
      ->get();




       $jcr['jcr'] = DB::table('og_ratings_jcr as t')

               ->select('t.client_id as id',
                't.jcr_dissemination_date as Dissemination', 
                't.rating_type_id as ratingTypeId',
                't.rating_scale_id',  
                't.jcr_action as Action' , 'og_companies.name as Entity',
                't.press_release_jcr as PressRelease',
                'og_actions.title as RatingAction',
                'og_outlooks.title as Outlook',
                'og_sterms.title as RatingST',
                'og_lterms.title as RatingLT',
                'og_segments.title',
                'og_rating_scales.title as RatingScale',
                'og_fund_types.title as fundtype',
                't.isActive as isActive' , 'og_main_sectors.title AS Industry' )
          ->get();

           return view('RatingsPacra', compact('pacra' , 'jcr'));
}
```

Comment: There's an extra `,` after `DetailReport` is  that a typo ? Also which line is the undefined variable coming from ?

Comment: there is not any syntax error in controller. Error shows in view files when i print the value (@foreach $pacra as $data)  $data->Entity (@endforeach)  here it shows property Entity not exist

Comment: You declare your result as `$pacra['pacra']`   so you need to do `foreach ($pacra['pacra'] as $data)`

Answer (score 1):

I found that you have missing the relations between the tables, as well as the extra `,` that @apokryfos mentioned.

Try something like:

```
public function ratingData()
{
    $pacra['pacra'] = \DB::connection()
        ->table('og_ratings')
        ->leftJoin('og_companies', 'og_companies.id', '=', 'og_ratings.og_companies_id')
        ->leftJoin('og_main_sectors', 'og_main_sectors.id', '=', 'og_ratings.og_main_sectors_id')
        ->select([
            'og_ratings.client_id as Id',
            'og_ratings.ppl_date as Ppl',
            'og_ratings.notification_date as Notification',
            'og_ratings.dissemination_date as Dissemination',
            'og_ratings.rating_type_id as ratingTypeId',
            'og_ratings.rating_scale_id',
            'og_ratings.pacra_action as Action',
            'og_companies.name as Entity',
            'og_main_sectors.title as Industry',
            'og_ratings.detail_report as DetailReport',
        ])
        ->get();

    $jcr['jcr'] = \DB::connection()
        ->table('og_ratings_jcr')
        ->leftJoin('og_actions', 'og_actions.id', '=', 'og_ratings_jcr.og_actions_id')
        ->leftJoin('og_outlooks', 'og_outlooks.id', '=', 'og_ratings_jcr.og_outlooks_id')
        ->leftJoin('og_sterms', 'og_sterms.id', '=', 'og_ratings_jcr.og_sterms_id')
        ->leftJoin('og_lterms', 'og_lterms.id', '=', 'og_ratings_jcr.og_lterms_id')
        ->leftJoin('og_segments', 'og_segments.id', '=', 'og_ratings_jcr.og_segments_id')
        ->leftJoin('og_rating_scales', 'og_rating_scales.id', '=', 'og_ratings_jcr.og_rating_scales_id')
        ->leftJoin('og_fund_types', 'og_fund_types.id', '=', 'og_ratings_jcr.og_fund_types_id')
        ->select([
            'og_ratings_jcr.client_id as id',
            'og_ratings_jcr.jcr_dissemination_date as Dissemination',
            'og_ratings_jcr.rating_type_id as ratingTypeId',
            'og_ratings_jcr.rating_scale_id',
            'og_ratings_jcr.jcr_action as Action', 'og_companies.name as Entity',
            'og_ratings_jcr.press_release_jcr as PressRelease',
            'og_actions.title as RatingAction',
            'og_outlooks.title as Outlook',
            'og_sterms.title as RatingST',
            'og_lterms.title as RatingLT',
            'og_segments.title',
            'og_rating_scales.title as RatingScale',
            'og_fund_types.title as fundtype',
            'og_ratings_jcr.isActive as isActive', 'og_main_sectors.title AS Industry',
        ])
        ->get();

    return view('RatingsPacra', compact('pacra', 'jcr'));
}
```

Where you should change the foreign keys between the tables as you have them.

You can still keep using table aliases, I just prefer not to use them, because they sometimes don't work as expected in Laravel / Doctrine Dbal.

I also updated the method name from `ratingdata` to `ratingData` for PSR-1 standards compliance:

https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/

You can also get back `\DB:connection()->table(..` to `DB::table(...`, that's only a opinionated way to do it.

Comment: There is no problem in my object. when i run one by one Query is ok no errors. but when both at same time it shows error

Comment: Can you give us more information about the error?

Maybe you can do a `dd($pacra, $jcr);` and share with us the result.

Or if the error is thrown before, maybe you can copy and paste it from `storage/logs/laravel.log` (or the storage/logs/*.log) you got.

You can run `tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log`, in a console terminal, from your project directory.